# Java Efficient Ways to auto-save text files

Tags: java, performance, text-files, bufferedwriter, autosave

I am trying to create a Text Editor with an "Auto-Save" feature. This means that whenever the user makes any changes to the current text (e.g. appends or deletes letters, words, lines, etc) then that change should be immediately applied to the text file as well.

I use a "TextArea" control from Javafx to detect any changes in the text. Also, I use a BufferedWriter to write the new text to the file, from scratch, whenever a change is detected.
However that doesn't seem correct to me, because the BufferedWriter will have to re-write all the text from scratch. This will cause performances issues if the text is too big.

Does anyone have a better idea of how to Implement this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, you do not need a buffer on your file writer. Buffered writing/reading is for *inefficient* writing in reading. So, for example, if you were writing to your file line by line or over time rather than all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use a timer, and write the update only if the document has been modified.

The example given works with Swing components, but can be adapted to other frameworks

```
boolean dirtyFlag = false; // set true if the document is altered
DocumentListener dl = new DocumentListener() { ... // implement all methods and set dirtyFlag = true in each
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    //save the file
  }
}
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixeRate(task, ..., ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone inserts or deletes near the start of the file, then most all of the file will have to be rewritten anyway.

So your strategy has to be about how you make the autosave appear effortless. For that you probably want to write the output to a backup file on a thread, and only when that backup is safely written, move it over the previous backup. Clearly, you can only start recording the next backup after the first has finished, so you can't record every change this way.

Another strategy is to write a journal of the changes, and these can be re-applied when the user chooses to restore. Every so often you could write a new complete backup, and then reset the journal. This journal would be the same data you use for undo/redo probably.

Comment: ok, but what If the user chooses to close the file instead of restoring it? Or if the power shuts down?

Comment: @user6115152 Then your program will have to ask the user next time they start up if they want to replay the journal since the last full backup, or restore from the last full backup. Have you never used excel? You are probably storing these journal or backup files somewhere your application knows about, so a quick scan at startup will reveal if there are any that need restoring or deleting.